# Moderators don't hunt down "questionable grammar"

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation, company, community-managers

In the description for the job opening [Vice President of Community Management](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3131115/vice-president-of-community-management) - which I'm glad to see you're hiring for - there's this line:

> We have a network of over 500 volunteer moderators who are dedicated to ensuring that the content on each of our sites is correct and easy to understand. They closely monitor our sites for things from duplicate questions to harassment to questionable grammar as they work to grow the sites that they have been elected to manage.

First of all, moderators *aren't* responsible for "ensuring that the content on each of our sites is correct and easy to understand". Anybody can edit a post to make it easier to understand, and as for "correct" that's what votes are for. Any user of the site can do these.

"questionable grammar" also falls under editing that anyone can do.

Duplicate questions *can* be handled by moderators, but really, that's something that can be handled by, again, regular users; flags and close votes work just fine.

All in all, this is a rather... misleading description of what moderators do.

What moderators *do* handle is flags. They deescalate situations. They hunt down sockpuppets. They serve as human exception handlers, help act as a liason between Community Managers and the community, and serve as examples.

Could this please be updated to reflect more closely on what moderators *actually* do?

Comment: I *did* hunt for any questionable grammer in this post, but sadly found none to prove the point :P

Comment: While technically not really in our current bucket of things to status review - I feel like this is something that really needs to be made clear to future candidates.

Comment: Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzdxeBTm6gk <--- Us hunting questionable grammar.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell You didn't notice the unhyphenated de-escalate? :p

Comment: @Nick I never made any promises about the quality of my hunting! :P

Comment: Moderators are responsible for the quality of the community of a site, not the quality of the content. The community is responsible for the quality of the content.

Comment: Eh... maybe that is why @JourneymanGeek was deemed not qualified for being CM... he failed in hunting bad grammar... You cant be a CM if you are wasting your time as moderator doing other, totally irrelevant things...

Comment: Maybe it's time to introduce a "Bad Grammar" flag to the system? Or we can just custom mod flag: "Please go hunts for them bad grammars what's in this posts."

Comment: Fixing questionable grammar is Glorfindel's job.

Comment: And moderators handle reports of plagiarism(?). That could be added to the examples.

Comment: “Any user of the site can do these” new users just don’t exist?

Comment: @EkadhSingh - New users fall under "any user" as well :)

Comment: @Mithical but new users cannot vote, and cannot edit (but they can suggest edits)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who voiced concerns and feedback on this JD. There were some grammatical changes made. The paragraph on moderators was updated by the CM team because everyone agreed that wasn't accurate.

Comment: The issue with using periods or not isn't correct in the first list.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `JD` is actually HR shorthand for "Job Description"? It's not something I've ever actually seen before. Might be an idea to edit that and delete this comment? (the JD I know is the one you get in for xmas and have mixers with :p)

Comment: So [mission accomplished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QFtA.jpg) I guess ;)

Comment: @JonClements yes JD is shorthand for Job Description. ;)

Answer (score 56):

More questionable grammar:

- "meet our users needs" is missing an apostrophe after "users"
- "our community, it’s goals and challenges" has an extra apostrophe in "it's"
- "in order to to" has an extra "to"
- "role playing games" should be hyphenated (as it is in the site name)
- "Dev Ops" should be one word (as it is in the site name)
- "topics from Parenting, to Dev Ops, to crypto, to role playing games" should use consistent capitalization ("parenting" is not a proper noun, though "DevOps" arguably is)
- "Our network of sites host" should say "hosts"—the subject is "network," not "sites"
- Inconsistent use of Oxford commas: some places (e.g., "establish, measure and achieve  goals and objectives" and "strategy,  policy and process") omit it, while others (e.g., "learnings, sharing, and career development" and "support users, work collaboratively with  internal stakeholders, and build") use it.
- "community facing", "user facing", etc. should be hyphenated

---

<sup>Also, before someone tells me that the commas in this post go inside the quotes: I know, but this way it's easier to select the entire quote and search the post for it.</sup>

Comment: re: the commas inside the quotes thing...I always hated this rule. Was taught it throughout elementary and middle school in the US. Only very recently did I learn that UK folks do the sensible thing and keep the quotes inside and the punctuation outside (unless it's part of the thing being quoted, "like this!", etc) and it isn't really wrong at all outside a US-school-system context (and US-based style guides).

Comment: You're my hero. (Not sarcastic.)

Comment: @BryanKrause Just adopt British spelling and you'll be fine. They'll be so busy correcting 'realise' they'll miss the stray comma :)

Comment: @ColleenV Never works for me :D

Answer (score 37):

While they are at it, they can also remove the extra space in these sentences:

- `work collaboratively with  internal stakeholders`
- `measure and achieve  goals and objectives for their team and the overall group`
- `Empower the team to work  hand in hand`
- `Manage the  team through multiple projects`
- `leading a community facing  team with millions`
- `customer and/or community  support with`
- `from  triage to identifying longer term solutions`

Then use one of those spaces to add here:

`10+years in a community or` (lacking a space after the + sign)

Fix grammar here:

- `Our network of sites host over 100  millions unique users` into `over 100 million`
- `Create opportunities for learnings, sharing, and career development opportunities` (I never heard of learnings opportunities before)
- `product teams in order to to build tools and features` (this sounds like we want them to be a train, to to)

Be consistent in the use of periods in the several lists. Some list items end with a period, while others don't. According to your own [style guide on lists](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#lists) none of these list items should be punctuated.

Answer (score 10):

A couple more, for good measure:

- "What you'll get in return:" is bolded, but the other headings aren't.
- "Employment is conditioned upon successful completion of a background check and upon having the appropriate legal right to work" is listed under "What you'll get in return," and while I suppose it's technically true that you'd receive this, it doesn't fall under the general understanding of a job perk, so probably belongs a bit later with the legalese.