# Thank you, moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

To all moderators on the Stack Exchange network, whether on strike or not:

**Thank you.**

Thank you for the countless hours you've spent keeping these sites usable, at least before the strike. Thank you for now doing what you feel is best for the community.

To those of you who are on strike, thank you for resisting corporate-imposed policies that prevent you from removing problematic content.

To those of you who are still moderating, thank you for continuing to do what you can to help despite these restrictive policies.

Comment: We already have one "thanks" post for this event, [This community is the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389835/this-community-is-the-stack-exchange-network) - I really don't see the point of another. You can also express thanks by answering that question.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is a "thanks" without mentioning thanks, saying that the community is great; it's more praise than thanks; so not a duplicate. Possibly equal 'duplicates' are: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/282094 is status-review, update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/282094 and this is the link to the prior unrest: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/282094 - also not really close enough to be a duplicate; but of interest is that a council of representatives has been chosen and the progress is written up in the links above; where thanks could also be expressed.