# Does the company acknowledge misusing the press, and why won't it agree on a no-comment policy?

Tags: discussion, moderation, policy

As people continue to comment trying to get me on their side about what is right or wrong to do (and probably voting based on that) I am sadly forced to add this notice to point out what I assumed was already clear.

***This is not a post that aims at judging what has been done nor have I posted this to get someone to convince me of what is happening.***
***The only reasoning behind this post is prompting the company to give their version of the story since the users here only get second-hand reports that are often confused like this was some sort of weird [Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) game or are simply removed from accessing relevant information that has been discussed privately.***
***The immediate result of this is that every time the current crisis ends, the normal users are left with an incomplete, misguided, and often incorrect view of what the two factions' positions were, what their argumentation was, and so on.***

Deciding what to do with said info is something every user will then have to do on their own.

---

The 2023-06-26 update of Zoe's answer on the "[Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390106/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh)" contains the following passage.

> **Issue: Stack Exchange, Inc. made inappropriate comments to the press**.
> Progress: We are debating this issue and have not yet reached a conclusion. **Stack is so far unwilling to agree to a blanket policy of "no comment" when asked for comment on anything involving moderators**; we are considering what our options are here. Stack Exchange, Inc. would like to keep open the option of commenting on general moderator actions not taken by an individual; the representatives are pushing for Stack to refrain commenting even about groups of moderators. **Stack has also indicated that they think it would be unfair for the company to be bound to not comment while individual moderators are free to comment, citing my own personal statements to the press. I've reminded them that they are a billion-dollar company, while we are a group of volunteers.**

On paper, this *should* be a reasonable enough thing, but most users seem to think that the reason the moderators made that request is that the company has a record of misrepresenting the ongoing issues when talking to the press, either by blatantly lying, taking stuff out of context, or omitting relevant parts of the truth to their advantage as shown by the recent "[Dear SE, please stop disparaging the moderators in the press](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389824/dear-se-please-stop-disparaging-the-moderators-in-the-press/389868#389868)".

Since, as far as I know, there never was a **public** statement about this, I am posting this question to give the company the opportunity to explain their position to the **entire user base** as it should be done (no, I don't care if this has been done "in secret" in some masonry meeting about the strike that regular users can't attend and moderators are forced to not talk about).

The two questions are simple:

- **Does Stack Exchange recognize that they have been misusing the press against their volunteers by publishing articles that contained a single-sided representation of the issues at best, and a complete misrepresentation at worst?**
- **Why does Stack Exchange think that the press is a useful tool for handling issues that should be solved by talking with their volunteers instead of name-calling them publicly?**

I don't think anyone will be willing to collaborate after you tried to tar and feather them on the main plaza.

Comment: As stated in Discord, there was a false belief within the company that moderators are unwilling to explain their actions, which led to an internal policy that staff should never reach out to mods to have them explain their actions. As part of the negotiations, SE was shown that the majority of mods do in fact welcome questions about their actions and so they (apparently) changed their internal policy to reflect this.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I don't really see how this is relevant. My question here is why the company doesn't want to give up the ability to talk about its volunteers to the press. And knowing if they acknowledge to have misused that power is also a big part in understanding their rationale and deciding if you can accept it.

Comment: I feel that my comment addresses your second question: because of the (likely, hopefully previous) policy of not discussing actions with moderators, SE probably felt that it was necessary to speak about their actions to the press since that's the only other forum they could be widely heard.

Comment: I see your rationale, I wouldn't buy that. Especially since that post on Ericson blog seems to indicate that employees too were given some incomplete version of the story in the recent  strike. Therefore, the action seems to be a deliberate move to be able to play on a domesticated ground and avoid fair debate. Also your idea imho doesn't make much sense for another reason: the public is different. On the network you are talking to your users. But who are you talking to on the press? Notice that the company NEVER had made their articles know to "us". We always had some users stumble into them.

Comment: Therefore the press doesn't seem to be a "safe ground" to talk to the users. It has been used as a single-sided ground to talk **about** the users with no easy way to reply all while keeping those interactions secret for the most part.

Comment: I think it’s unreasonable to insist on a blanket policy that the company can’t say anything about a huge part of its platform to the press. Yes, it’s wrong (and dumb) to publicly disparage the people donating their time to the company but if I were in their shoes, I wouldn’t agree to never being able to mention volunteer moderators to the press under any circumstances. Maybe I would agree to giving the volunteers a heads up prior to commenting though.Sometimes having to say something to someone directly makes you think a little harder about what you’re saying about them.

Comment: As long as the press is unbiased and available equally to SE and the users, I dont see why SE has to be forced to not say their side of the story just because they are the company. As for the other side being volunteers, they are always free to stop volunteering if they feel exploited. I dont think being volunteers implies they can demand any special treatment during the conflict

Comment: @user13267 the word of a billion dollar company is taken more seriously than that of a couple volunteers. Nobody wants a repeat of what happened with Monica. We can debate what the details of the proposed policy should be, but in the end of the day the restriction on SE should definitely be significantly stronger than the restriction on a volunteer moderator since the former can actually cause serious damage to the latter.

Comment: @MissSkooter sure but the restriction should not be them not getting to defend themselves by not being allowed to say their side of the story. And what serious damage are you talking about? As far as I know SE doesn't pay their rent or anything like that

Comment: @user13267 Misrepresenting a named individual on the net could have serious impact on her professional career. Furthermore the specific case could also paint her as a potential target to social harassing

Comment: Who is the named individual on the net in this situation? As far as i know most of the people who are "negotiating" with SE on this arent using real names. And even if they did they are the ones who stood up and wanted to be "negotiators". And again, what does that have to do with SE telling their side of the story? Them telling their side of the story and slandering someone are different things. I said they should be allowed to defend themselves. Just because there is a possibility of slandering someone doesn't mean they should be prevented from talking about their side

Comment: @user13267 "Who is the named individual on the net in this situation? " - read again the message fro Miss Skooter you initially replied to.

Comment: I'mma tell you straight up, you're not going to get an answer about this out in the open.  I feel this type of question only further calcifies the company in believing that we're really out to get them, and in reality you're just looking for some clarification.  Just remember the positions we find ourselves in; we're a loosely organized group of passionate volunteers who want the greater good to prevail, and they have to put food on the table.  So I don't really believe that you'd get an answer to this directly; you'd have to wait on the negotiation team to hear back on this, I think.

Comment: Tangentially, see also now https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391255/mod-strike-is-it-realistic-to-require-a-no-comment-press-policy

Comment: Either both sides or neither side of a conflict should be able to state their point of view. Only allowing it for one side is unfair. (And censorship is seldom the solution).

Comment: A bit of an update: after some more chatting, it came out that the statements attributed to Philippe (and mistakenly to Prashanth) in the press weren't actually written by Philippe; they were put out by a PR team with Philippe's name on it and were never actually approved by Philippe. The team has now agreed to enact a new internal policy that anything that goes out in anyone's name must now be explicitly approved by said person.